# Jstree not assigning an id to li element

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, bind, jstree

I have an instance of jstree. It is ajax with json.

Here is how I am creating the tree.

```
        $("#tree").jstree({
            "plugins" : ["themes", "json_data", "ui"],
            "json_data" : {
                "ajax" : {
                    "type": 'GET',
                    "url": function (node) {
                        var nodeId = "";
                        var url = ""
                        if (node == -1)
                        {
                            //first url called is static
                            url = "myUrl";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                           //click on a node "li", get the id, append it to the url.
                           nodeId = node.attr('id');
                           url = "myUrl" + nodeId;
                        }

                        return url;
                    },
                    "success": function (new_data) {
                       //get the data topNode out of the json object
                       new_data = new_data.topNode;

                       return new_data;
                    }
                }
            },

        });
```

Here is the output.

```
<div id="tree" class="jstree-classic jstree jstree-0 jstree-focused jstree-default">
    <ul>
        <li class="jstree-closed jstree-last">
            <ins class="jstree-icon">&nbsp;</ins>
            <a class="" href="#">Item 1</a> 
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

However when the tree is rendered the  <LI> element does not have an id. Should be automatically appended to the <LI>. What am i missing?

Comment: Does your ajax return id in the json?

Comment: yes. if i alert newData.topNode.id i get the correct response.

Comment: What is the structure of your '`new_data`?

Comment: {"topNode":{"data":"Item 1","children":[],"state":"closed","id":"1","attributes":{"class":"editContainerLink","href":"#"}}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If below is your data returned from ajax call you need to move `"id":"1"` to **attributes** section

```
{"topNode":{"data":"Item 1",
            "children":[],
            "state":"closed",
            "id":"1",
            "attributes":{"class":"editContainerL‌​ink","href":"#"}
           }
}
```

so it would look like

```
{"topNode":{"data":"Item 1",
            "children":[],
            "state":"closed",
            "id":"1",
            "attributes":{"class":"editContainerL‌​ink",
                          "href":"#",
                          "id":"1"
                          }
           }
}
```

Comment: I changed it to this format and it still does not populate the id. `  {"topNode":{"data":"Item 1",
            "children":[],
            "state":"closed",
            "attributes":{"class":"editContainerL‌​ink","href":"#", "id":"1"}
           }
    }`

Comment: So id needs to be defined twice?

Comment: Combining both your solution of moving into the attributes area, then...
Changing "attributes" to "attr" fixed the problem. the id is now populated in the LI.

    {"topNode":{"data":"Item 1",
            "children":[],
            "state":"closed",
             "attr":{"class":"editContainerL‌​ink",
                          "href":"#",
                          "id":"1"
                          }
           }
    }

Comment: Why would have to be id's defined twice?

Answer (score 0):

just change attributes to attr and an id will appear in the 'a' node. I also want the id in the 'li' node but until now my tries with metadata are not successful.

```
// the `metadata` property will be saved using the jQuery `data` function on the `li` node
"metadata" : "a string, array, object, etc",
```

from:
http://www.jstree.com/documentation/json_data